# Trouble converting all items in list rather than just the last item

Tags: python, arrays

Im doing an assignment for my Script Programming class and I'm having a lot of trouble. Here is the prompt:

> Unix time/Epoch time is the number of seconds since midnight of January 1st 1970. Write a Python function named convert_utime() that reads the timestamps from a file named unixttimestamp.txt (see attached) and displays the human readable form of the supplied Unix timestamp.

Everything works as intended for the most part, however, it is only reading, converting and outputing the last line of my array rather than all of them. Here is what I have so far:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\bailey\\Downloads\\unixtimestamp.txt') as file:
    utime_list = [line.rstrip() for line in file]

utime_list = [line[7:] for line in utime_list]


import datetime

for line in utime_list:
    epochTime = float(line)
    humanTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(epochTime))
print("Epoch time: ", epochTime, "Converted time: ", humanTime)
```

Comment: Just move that last line *inside* the loop?

Comment: You don't need to write `float(epochTime)`. You already converted it to a float on the previous line. Also, you should probably be using `int()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Almost right! Just an indentation error.

```
with open('C:\\Users\\bailey\\Downloads\\unixtimestamp.txt') as file:
    utime_list = [line.rstrip() for line in file]

utime_list = [line[7:] for line in utime_list]


import datetime

for line in utime_list:
    epochTime = float(line)
    humanTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(epochTime))

    # This should be indented, i.e. _inside_ the loop, as pointed out by @trincot in the comments
    print("Epoch time: ", epochTime, "Converted time: ", humanTime)
```